# Why is Android Studio cleaning before build?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build-time

Since a specific upgrade on Android Studio (unfortunately I can't remember exactly the version, because I had this problem since some months ago, but I'm just asking now), my build times are very high, something between 4 and 5 minutes. And this is happening because of this:

[Bar showing that a "clean" task is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd579.png)

Why is Android Studio cleaning the project when I build the app? Sometimes I didn't even changed anything in the app - seriously: sometimes, a connection error occurs when installing the app in the emulator, so I click the "play" button again and... Android Studio cleans and rebuilds the entire project again).

Anyone knows why is this happening and how to avoid this issue?

I could not find anyone with this kind of problem when searching on Google, and I don't know if it only happens with my project or it is because the majority apps are not that big, so the rebuild time is not relevant...

Answer (score 0):

honestly i have no idea what is happening, but why don't you try to turning off the instant run?

(File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run)